# Where can I find the default back button chevron image for iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm working on updating an old app that uses UIButtons that are meant to mimic a navigation bar's back button in appearance. I'd like to use the default chevron image that's used for back buttons in  iOS 7.

Is this image available somewhere in the iOS 7 SDK or elsewhere so I can use it as a UIButton's image via `setImage:forState:`?

Comment: https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy - using the artwork extractor, the correct image is UINavigationBarBackIndicatorDefault@2x.png in the UIKit framework UIKit_NewArtwork section. If you want to add an answer with that information, I'll accept it.

Comment: Just curious, why the down votes?

Comment: check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807997/back-button-image-what-is-it-called-in-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If you need to extract image from iOS, this is the best tool:

[iOS-Artwork-Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor/).

I think you would be able to extract chevron image with it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not available through any published, Apple authorized API. Some options available to you are:

1. See if somebody else has extracted the artwork files and provides instructions or tools for you to do so yourself.
2. Take a screenshot of the UI element, then use that yourself.
3. Write code to draw it yourself; in the case of the back button chevron, it is a fairly simple image (two lines, a few pixels think, rounded caps) and wouldn't be hard to reproduce with a few Core Graphics calls.

Comment: I'd add another suggestion to this - grab the image and import it into photoshop or another drawing application then trace over it.