# Changing back button title to default < icon

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I made a custom back button but I want to change the title to the default arrow "<" how do I do this? This is what I currently have

```
let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "back:")
```

I need "Back" to be the default "<" icon. When I type it in as text it's just a small ugly text button.

[image]

Comment: you need only "<" or you need "< Back"

Comment: I editted my question and that's what I get when I put <

Comment: Have you looked at other solutions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807997/back-button-image-what-is-it-called-in-swift Most people use an image.

Comment: Yea but if possible I would like to use the default image and not load an extra image for it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use some font-icon library [like ionicons](https://github.com/sweetmandm/ionicons-iOS) to get what you need.
In provided link there are library and examples how install and how to use it.
It's quite useful because with a font icon you don't need to bother with image sizes and scaling.

To set "back" icon on button you only need to do something like this:

```
self.button.setTitle(String.fontIonIconWithName("ios-arrow-back"), forState: .Normal)
```

Here is [official website](http://ionicons.com/) where you can find all available icons.

Comment: Good Hint! Took some minutes to find it, so for everyone else's convenience the .fontIonIconWithName() method is part of this library: https://github.com/0x73/SDevIconFonts

Answer (score 3):

You could put this line into `viewDidLoad` method

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

This way you will get standard "<" sign without any label

*EDIT*

Swift notation:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // only standard '<' will appear; proper target and action will be added automatically
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain , target: nil, action: nil)
}
```

Comment: I hope it won't be a problem to translate this to Swift notation ;-)

Comment: I never worked with Objective C before and I tried to translate but it doesn't work since the parameter like initWithTitle is deprecated

Comment: @SinanSamet - I updated the answer. Btw you use Swift analog of `initWithTitle:::` initialiser in your question

Comment: Ah I get it now. But the problem with this is that I am using a custom back button in which I hide the back button and use `leftBarButtonItem`. I think that's the problem and I should try using the icons instead.