# iOS 11 NavigationBar back button issue

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, backbarbuttonitem

I set backbarbutton in a base ViewController viewDidLoad like below:

```
    if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {

    UIImage *backButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_return"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backButtonImage;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backButtonImage;

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
}
```

but I got a small icon, but is not in the correct position
[image]

who can give me some tips, I have spent a whole day to solve this, but can not get any idea.

Comment: Check the back button image size. This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31808361/5167909

Comment: The image size is 22*44 for 1x, 66*132 for 3x. But i found in Debug View  Hierarchy  got it 's frame  is  22, 32.6667